# Do these depictions of hunt in medieval Catholic churches have the same symbolic meaning? If not, what is it?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, christianity, art, symbols

I have come across 3 depictions of a hunt in Catholic churches.

The first two are tiles that were on the floors of [an English abbey](https://twitter.com/wabbey/status/1143861747989778433) and [a church not far from Reims, France](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Carreau_m%C3%A9di%C3%A9val_Laon_030208_06.jpg); I could not find any analysis. They seem to be out of tune, given the devotional nature of the churches.

The third one is a fresco from a Mozarabic church. There is [a Wikipedia article that discusses it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Baudelio_de_Berlanga). It reads: `on the right is a hunter riding a horse, helped by three dogs chasing hares, which end up trapped in the forest. The hare is a symbol in Christian iconography of the fragility of the soul and strong sexual desire or lust, which must be harassed and overcome.`

Is there a similar meaning behind hunters shown on the tiles? If not, what is it?

Are there other depictions of the hunt in medieval Christian churches? What was the evolution of the depictions of the hunt in medieval Christian churches, if applicable?

[image: hunting in churches]

Comment: I'm seeing number of sources that mention hunting (especially rabbit hunting) as a lazy/lustful/sinful sort of activity in the medieval European context, in one case as a potential distraction from church-going, but nothing specific to how it is represented in churches so far.